# git submodule error - picking up latest commit instead of a specific commit

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, git-submodules

I have a repository with a submodule which includes 3 files:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you see here, the branch specified in `.gitmodules` is 'develop' and the ref specified in `vsts-cicd.yml` is 'develop'.

The git command I use to update the commit is:

> git submodule update --remote --merge

My understanding was that when we do a deployment, it will get the changes from 'public' submodule up to the commit specified in 'public' (in this case: 1ff703eda1b357efdecbffb2422b6fcc99a48557). But what I noticed is that, if I have a new commit in 'develop' in 'public', it will pick that latest commit from 'develop' even though 'public' submodule has an old commit '1ff703eda1b357efdecbffb2422b6fcc99a48557'. Is that how submodule works? Please let me know what I am missing?

Note: When I run

```
cd submodule; git log
```

I see the latest commit listed as 1ff703eda1b357efdecbffb2422b6fcc99a48557 (which is correct)